# Referencing binding annotations dynamically in Polymer 1

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to set up a function in Polymer 1.0 which will allow a JSON response to tell my application which `{{BindingVariable}}` in which to insert the response. Unfortunately, the syntax for referencing these binding variables seems to be similar to this:`this.BindingVariable`, which doesn't allow for dynamic variable names.

What I really need is a way to reference these dynamically like how we can reference anything else in the DOM/PolyDOM. For example: `document.querySelector('#'+elementID)`.

Is there any way to reference binding annotations dynamically? I've searched through the entire Polymer DOM and can't find them listed anywhere even though I know they're in the page.

**example**

```
app._onResponseRetrieved = function(e) {
  for (var key in e.detail.response) {
    // none of these work, but they demonstrate what I'm trying to accomplish

    // this.key = e.detail.response[key];
    // this.querySelector(key) = e.detail.response[key];
    // window[key] = e.detail.response[key];
    // document[key] = e.detail.response[key];
    // Polymer.dom(key) = e.detail.response[key];
    }
```

**JSON Sent to _onResponseRetrieved**

```
{"contactFormOutput":"Success!"}
```

**Binding Annotation in index.html**

```
<div>{{contactFormOutput}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this[key] = e.detail.response[key];`

Javascript allows `[]` on any object for dynamic property referencing